# nHibernate statistics per session

Tags: nhibernate

I know I can get global statistics for nHibernate using these techniques

http://nhibernate.info/blog/2008/10/26/exploring-nhibernate-statistics-part-1-simple-data-fetching.html

What I'm after is a way to get statistics for the current session in the current thread.

EG, I want to know how many entities where loaded in my session, how many db queries made, etc.

I see Hibernating Rhinos can break down stats per session, so NH must be storing it in some form?

dave

Comment: Were you ever able to get per-session query statistics?  I've been looking to do the same, and am disappointed to see only Entity and Collection count on the session stats.

Comment: Sorry Matt, I never did find a way

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `ISessionFactory.Statistics`, just use `ISession.Statistics`.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ISession session = NHibernateHelper.GetSession();
        var stats = session.Statistics;
        Console.WriteLine("Entity count: {0}", stats.EntityCount);
        Console.WriteLine("Collection count: {0}", stats.CollectionCount);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Statistics at the session level are limited when compared with the session factory level though.

Comment: Thanks for that and I did notice there were session level statistics, but the only 2 stats at the session level are Entity and Collection count.  I'm also after db queries being made.